# node server start using php work in localhost but in live site it return errors

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, npm, server

I complete a project in Node.js with mysql database
but to start node.js server i make a php file which simply call `exec('set DEBUG=myapp:* & npm start')` function and it also work in localhost but in live site when i upload it and try to run, it make 'npm-debug.log' & server can not start npm-debug.log description is as bellow mention.

---

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.9
3 info using node@v6.9.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle myapp@0.0.0~prestart: myapp@0.0.0
6 silly lifecycle myapp@0.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle myapp@0.0.0~start: myapp@0.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle myapp@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle myapp@0.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:******************/myapp/node_modules/.bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
10 verbose lifecycle myapp@0.0.0~start: CWD: ******************/myapp
11 silly lifecycle myapp@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'node ./bin/www' ]
12 silly lifecycle myapp@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle myapp@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: myapp@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:255:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid myapp@0.0.0
16 verbose cwd /******************/myapp
17 error Linux 2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.x86_64
18 error argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
19 error node v6.9.2
20 error npm  v3.10.9
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error myapp@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the myapp@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the myapp package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     node ./bin/www
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs myapp
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls myapp
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: I think you need to run node server use [link](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2). use pm2  instead  `exec('set DEBUG=myapp:* & npm start')`

Answer (score -1):

To run the command on Live Server we must provide ssh authentication so without authentication it will not fire any command.

for that i use php's [ssh2_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php) function which allowing to pass ssh credentials and make a session of the connection then execute any commands.

Thanks.

Comment: If that is the solution then you've not understood (or explained) the problem very well